# Django restframework generics.ListCreateAPIView returns list like objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class UserProfileView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (
    permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def list(self,request):
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I've got out pull like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "exp",
    "lastname": "exp"
  }
]
```

I wanted like this,How can i do that and i don't know why it's returning list like object, How can i fix this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "exp",
    "lastname": "exp",
}
```

Comment: The returned result is a regular model schema, as far as I am concerned...

Comment: List is to retrieve *multiple* of records, Retrieve is for the single ones - they have separated method: get_object()

Comment: @Jerzyk Can you give me any example how to do that  !!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListCreateAPIView` is designed to return list of objects.

Representation like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "exp",
    "lastname": "exp",
}
```

Means you want an object, not list of objects, which means you need to get desired object by using [`RetrieveAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview)

There are no `RetrieveCreateAPIView`, but you can easily make with [`RetrieveModelMixin`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrievemodelmixin)

Like this

```
from rest_framework import mixins, generics

class UserProfileView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    # Custom get_object method which is gets from request
    # instead of queryset
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

    # You can look this up in RetrieveAPIView
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Update**

You need to overload `get_object` method, by default `get_object` will look in passed url parameters and try to get object from provided queryest. It is made like this to be generic for CRUDL usage. After that returned value from `get_object` is used to instantiate `serializer_class`.  But in your case you need to just return current user in `request`. See updated answer. All this info can be understood if you look up `retrieve` method relaisation. For developer it is essential skill to know how to read source code.